# Block Excel Application from Showing

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I have a wpf application that opens/creates excel files and reads/writes to them. In the normal way of the application running, **no** excel window is shown to the user.

**The Scenario:**

Through my application, I browse to excel file "AAA.xlsx", and the application loads it. Then, I try to browse to another excel file, **but while on the browse window** I choose excel file "BBB.xlsx", right click it and select open, Excel launches with **both** files open.

If I do the same routine, but beforehand I had the Excel program already open(with or without a file loaded), only the selected file will open.

Below is the constructor

```
public ExcelManipulator()
{
   excelApp = new Excel.Application();
   excelApp.Visible = false; //not making any difference
   excelApp.IgnoreRemoteRequests = true; //not making any difference
   workbooks = excelApp.Workbooks;
   workbook = workbooks.Open(path);
   ...
}
```

My ultimate goal is the excel files that my application has loaded to be invisible from the user's screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to separate 'instances' of Excel.

Try the following.

```
Process process = new Process();
Process.Start("Excel.exe", myExcelFile);
```

Other option is, if you use Interop (i.e. Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll ), you can do it as follows. This will always open the file in a new instance.

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
excelApp.Visible = true;
string workbookPath = (@"C:\Sample.xlsx");
Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath,
    0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
    true, false, 0, true, false, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I think you missed my point. I don't want the excel files that are loaded to my application to be launched and visible to the user. Your code made no difference in the scenario that I described.